# How to create animation with gradient to fill whole button

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I got button with linear-gradient and I want to hover this button with animation from linear-gradient to only one color. In this case from linear yellow-red to just red.

```css
.button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: unset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red 35%, yellow 100%);;
  color: transparent;
}
button:hover {
   animation: ex 4s ease-out;
}

@keyframes ex {
  from {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, red 35%, yellow 100%);
  }
  to {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 35%, red 100%);;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button">xxxxxx</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another idea where you can animate `background-color`:

```css
.button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: unset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red 35%, transparent 100%);
  background-color:yellow;
  transition:2s background-color;
  color: transparent;
}
button:hover {
   background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">xxxxxx</button>
```

Another one with `background-position`

```css
.button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: unset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, red 32.5%);
  background-size:200% 100%;
  transition:2s background-position;
  color: transparent;
}
button:hover {
   background-position:right;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">xxxxxx</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inset red shadow to cover it up. In addition, it's better in this case to use a transition. Transition will work when you stop hovering the element, even in the middle of the animation.

```css
.button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: unset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red 0, red 77%, yellow 100%);
  background-size: 200%;
  color: transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px transparent;
  transition: box-shadow 4s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">xxxxxx</button>
```

And if you really want to use animation (check what happens when you stop hovering the element):

```css
.button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: unset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red 0, red 77%, yellow 100%);
  background-size: 200%;
  color: transparent;
  transition: box-shadow 4s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
   animation: ex 4s ease-out;
}

@keyframes ex {
  from {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px transparent;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px red;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button">xxxxxx</button>
```